# how do I turn this into a foursquare multi request?

Tags: json, api, foursquare

How do I turn this into a multi request for the foursquare API?

I'd like to have multiple queries, so &query=coffee, &query=tea, &query=juice

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=ZBILJIMSSXR0GAK1MKOPUQK5AXLG0QJR0G4YWYPRJBV4UTU4&client_secret=2WRE5DSPA10YCSNAHFJOFKYCBAXMKM0N4VVP2MWQIPDF5OM5&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=coffee

I've been looking at the [foursquare doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) and playing with [apigee](https://apigee.com/console/foursquare) to test requests, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Following the instructions of the docs, it should have the structure of `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=` followed by comma delimited list, like `/venues/search?&ll=40.7,-74&limit=10&radius=1000&query=coffee,/venues/search?&ll=40.7,-74&limit=10&radius=1000&query=tea`

The foursquare explorer automatically adds an auth token. So I didn't include it. But I still can't get it to work. I get irrelevant results and a 200 error (depreceated).

Comment: Looks like I also have to sanitize my coordinates so the comma doesn't make it seem like an additional request... `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=multi?requests=/venues/search?&v=20130815&ll=("40.70,-74.00")&limit=10&radius=1000&query=coffee,/venues/search?&v=20130815&ll=("40.70,-74.00")&limit=10&radius=1000&query=tea` However, I'm getting a 400 param error, " "ll must be of the form XX.XX,YY.YY (received ("40.70,74.00"))""

Answer (score 0):

You will have to double encode similar to what is documented in Factual Multi API (Encoding section).
http://developer.factual.com/api-docs/#Multi